# String replace in mat-autocomplete in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am beginner webdeveloper. I have this code:

```html
<input id="street{{sid}}" 
       name="street{{sid}}" 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="" 
       class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="adres.street" 
       #street="ngModel" 
       required="" 
       (keydown)="this.removeSpecialCharactersFromStreet($event)"
       (keyup)="this.removeSpecialCharactersFromStreet($event)"
       capitalize-first="true">
```

```
removeSpecialCharactersFromStreet(event) {
  this.adres.street = event.target.value.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.\]'":*?<>{}@^&=;'"_!\[]/g, '');
}
```

and it works fine.

Now I need to add this function to mat-autocomplete:

```
removeSpecialCharactersFromCity(event) {
  this.adres.city = event.target.value.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.\]'":*?<>{}@^&=;'"_!\[]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<mat-autocomplete 
       autoActiveFirstOption 
       #auto="matAutocomplete"
       (keydown)="this.removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)" 
       (keyup)="this.removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of cityFilteredOptions" 
              [value]="option"
              (keydown)="this.removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)" 
              (keyup)="this.removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

And it doesn't work.
How can I fix it?

Please help me

Comment: _"And it's not work"_ You should start by explaining what that means. How is it not working? What actually happens? What are you expecting to happen? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect autocomplete to your own input and then manipulate the input value as you did to the regular input:

```html
<input
  matInput
  [(ngModel)]="address.city"
  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  (keydown)="removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)"
  (keyup)="removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)">

<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of cityFilteredOptions" [value]="option">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

[Working example in stackblitz](https://angular-material-basic-setup-7e8fnz.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

Change the (keydown) and (keyup) event bindings on mat-autocomplete to (input) event binding.

```
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (input)="removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of cityFilteredOptions" [value]="option">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Update the removeSpecialCharactersFromCity function to use the event object directly.

```
removeSpecialCharactersFromCity(event: any) {
  this.adres.city = event.target.value.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.\]'":*?<>{}@^&=;'"_!\[]/g, '');
}
```

Edit:

Change

```
(input)="removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event)"
```

to

```
(input)="removeSpecialCharactersFromCity($event.target.value)
```